# <video> não respeita altura pré-definida e object-fit:cover no Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, html5-video

Estou chamando um vídeo em uma div pai com a seguinte definição:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

E como elemento filho a tag `<video>` com:

```
video {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

No Firefox Developer Edition funciona normalmente, tanto o crop do `object-fit` quanto a altura de `400px` mas no Chrome não. Ou o vídeo fica muito mais alto do que deveria ou em tela cheia (se eu usar `vh` como unidade).

Print:
[image: chrome x firefox html5 video e object-fit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é que o seu vídeo está extrapolando a medida do *container*. Uma forma para resolver isso é colocando `overflow:hidden` no *container*

Imagem feita no Chrome! (vr. 71)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Codigo da imagem acima:**

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <video controls>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!